# Call web services based on Bearer Authorization algorithm

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest

We have an android app and we should call some web services on it.
The back end services works on bearer authorization algorithm. When a user logged in, the server gives him an access token and this token is valid for about an hour.

When we call a service we send this token as a HTTP Header. If token is valid, it's OK. But when the token is not valid, the server gives us an error and we must call another service to get a new token and recall that service with this new token.

Are there any patterns to implement this workflow?

Comment: I can understand your use case but I can't seems to make out what the real issue is. Do you want to rephrase your question and  focus on asking specific things? Actually this sort of authentication framework is pretty standard today, you normally would request for tokens, which the service will give you back a refreshToken and an access Token. `Refresh token` is used for fetching a new `access token` when the old one has expired. Upon authentication you will use the `access_token` to call services which requires authentication to identify yourself.

Comment: @SamuelToh I need a design pattern. I guess we need a way to handle this in case one of the web service call failed. I don't know maybe we should simply call this services respectively .

Comment: I don't know of any design pattern for this problem. I think you just have to read the external party's web service documentation and handle the exception appropriately. E.g. If it gives you back a certain HTTP code and error which signal that the access token has expired then the code should call the appropriate token refresh API and retry the web service again with the new access token. Your solution will pretty much dependent on how the external party design its end point and exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which i have implemented earlier

1. Write an authentication function in your webservice, which will generate and store a TOKEN for the user. Then return that TOKEN if the credentials are okay
2. store the TOKEN in your android application in a secure way.
3. Use the TOKEN as a primary argument in every webservice call
4. For each webservice call, the token must be checked with the
   database
5. You can also use the token to identify the User
6. If the user logs in from another device, then the authentication function should generate a new TOKEN then stores and returns it (same as point no 1)
7. Then the new token only works with the webservice calls. The old authenticated device should return 'invalid token'

Comment: Token should be in memory/Cache (MemCache/Redis) (Not in database). Tokens are accessed frequently hence DB access will delay.

Comment: This is a layout of a Authentication Framework. You can also use InnoDB for the tokens table which will cache everything for you. The only thing you need to do is to increase the memory mysql uses. Other database vendors also have similar techniques to increase the performance of static row read.

Comment: @ChristlinJoseph As Viswanath said, server can't validate the token bacause of overhead on the server

Comment: @MojtabaMahamed can you tell us another best way to do it, because my next project involves a system based on tokens. Thanks in advance.